# HTML Dropdown вбок

Tags: html, css, html5, dropdown

[Здесь](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_dropdown_hover) - пример выпадающего меню вниз

Как его сделать вбок, как на картинке, именно влево

[image: Drop left]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простойвариант:
Просто замени свой стиль на вот этот:

```
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    left: 100%;
    top: -50%;
}
```

Comment: Сделал `left: -150`, а как его выставить, чтоб не было промежутка между кнопкой и списком меню? Ведь если будет промежуток, тогда меню скроется, и пользователь не сможет достучаться до этого меню

Comment: сделай left: -100%

Comment: заслоняет кнопку

Comment: Это нужно внутрь кнопки помещать, что бы можно было брать ширину кнопки и подгонять отступы уже с этими условиями)

Comment: Понял, спасибо)